# Using ReactJS Fullpage how to use onclick of image to go to section

Tags: reactjs, onclick, anchor, fullpage.js

I am using Fullpage React.  I want to click on a sidebar of circle images with numbers corresponding to the section I want to go to.  How do I activate the onclick? I have data anchors on the sections (ie section1, section2, etc) and on the images I have data menu anchors (ie, section1, section2, etc). I am doing all this in a class in my App.js. I can't seem to figure out how to use an onclick to tie the image being clicked to take it to that section with Fullpage.  I am able to scroll up and down to each section which is working fine.  I want to give the user the option to scroll and/or click to each section.

I used refs first and then added Fullpage for the scroll to section effect.  But my onclick with the refs stopped working. How can I get the onclick to each section working and keep the scroll effect to each section too?

```
<img className='circle-1' src='assets/images/circle1.png' onClick={() => this.clickToSection(this.section1ref.current)} data-menuanchor='section1'/>
<img className='circle-2' src='assets/images/circle1.png' onClick={() => this.clickToSection(this.section2ref.current)} data-menuanchor='section2'/>
<img className='circle-3' src='assets/images/circle2.png' onClick={() => this.clickToSection(this.section3ref.current)} data-menuanchor='section3'/>


<div className='section' ref={this.section1ref} data-anchor='section1'>
                SECTION 1
</div>

<div className='section' ref={this.section2ref} data-anchor='section2'>
                SECTION 2
</div>

<div className='section' ref={this.section3ref} data-anchor='section3'>
                SECTION 3 />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [the example in the official documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage#examples) for react-fullpage.

Basically:

```
<button onClick={() => fullpageApi.moveSectionDown()}>
    Click me to move down
</button>
```

You can see it in action here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/m34yq5q0qx

Comment: What if the button I click is not to move down to the next section but to jump to a different section that is 3 sections away?  Is it possible to target with a className?

Comment: Check the [fullpage.s documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) to see all the available functions in the API.